# Move location of tick marks in Seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I made a plot using the seaborn package. This is the code:

```
ax = sns.pointplot(x='latency_condition', y='flow', color=colors[0], ci=95, data=df_new,
                   scale=.5, linestyles='dotted', errwidth=2, capsize=.3)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
ax.set_xlabel("E(latency)", fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel("Flow score", fontweight='bold')
ax.set_yticklabels(['min','','','neutral','','','max'])
ax.set(ylim = (10,70))
plt.axhline(y=40, color=colors[3], linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.savefig("fig4_flow.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

This all works fine. Now, I have categorical levels on the x-axis on an interval level. They represent latency values, which are, unfortunately, 'ugly': [162, 245, 328, 412, 495, 578]

I would prefer it if my x-axis had tick marks per 100, for example, to improve readability. However, seaborn sees them (rightly so) as categorical levels, so I can't just change the x-axis.[image]

What I want to do is:

- remove the current xticks and replace them with new ones (e.g. per 100)
- do so in a way that the new xticks respect the coordinate system (since the old ones were also evenly spaced, representing the underlying continuum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is not a bad idea. `pointplot()` is meant to be used with categorical data, and using it with continuous data (even if your x-axis only take a few discrete values) is asking for trouble.

In any case, in seaborn's `pointplot()`, the levels of the categorical variables are plotted on the x-axis at coordinates 0,1,...,N-1. Since you know the value of the latency at each of these points, it's just a matter of doing a linear interpolation to find the x-value you need to have the round number of your choice:

```
ticks = [162, 245, 328, 412, 495, 578]
new_ticks = [150,250,350,450,550]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.random(size=(100,)), 'cat': np.random.choice(ticks, size=(100,))})

fig, (ax1, ax2)= plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,4))
ax1.set_title('original')
sns.pointplot(x='cat',y='value',data=df, ax=ax1)
ax2.set_title('rescaled')
sns.pointplot(x='cat',y='value',data=df, ax=ax2)

x_ticks = ax2.get_xticks()
s = (x_ticks[-1]-x_ticks[0])/(ticks[-1]-ticks[0])
i = x_ticks[0] - s*ticks[0]
new_x_ticks = s*np.asarray(new_ticks) + i

ax2.set_xticks(new_x_ticks)
ax2.set_xticklabels(new_ticks)
```

[image]

Comment: I share your concern on whether it's a good idea. It's something my coauthor and I are going back and forth on. Thank you for a very efficient solution!

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to use a secondary x-axis and set the limits corresponding to points -0.5 and 5.5:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some random data
N = 100
a = [162, 245, 328, 412, 495, 578]
x = np.random.choice(a, N)
y = np.random.normal(65 - x / 20, 10, N)
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'latency_condition':x, 'flow': y})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
sns.pointplot(ax=ax2, x='latency_condition', y='flow', color='dodgerblue', ci=95, data=df_new,
              scale=.5, linestyles='dotted', errwidth=2, capsize=.3)

# ax2.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
# ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
ax2.set_xlabel("")
ax1.set_xlabel("E(latency)", fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_xlim(1.5*a[0] - 0.5*a[1], -0.5*a[-2] + 1.5*a[-1])
ax1.set_ylabel("Flow score", fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_yticklabels(['min','','','neutral','','','max'])
ax1.set(ylim = (10,70))

ax1.axhline(y=40, color='crimson', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
#plt.savefig("fig4_flow.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Wow, this may be a solution to the discussion I've been having with my coauthor. Thanks!